# Duplicating A2DP sound output with paprefs

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I'm trying to play the sound output from my computer simultaneously in two bluetooth headsets using paprefs. While the sound plays in both devices, it seems only one of them can use the A2DP configuration (always the first that was connected), while the other gets stuck with the poor quality configuration. Despite the sound configuration panel lets me choose between A2DP and HSP, any selection leads to HSP sound for the device connected the second. Is this a limitation of the bluetooth adapter bandwidth?